# Как избавится от дублирования в JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет!
У меня есть 4 таблицы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно одним запросом объединить их. Но когда я пишу вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `store`
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `slider` GROUP BY id) AS x ON store.id = x.id_store
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `products` GROUP BY id) AS y ON store.id = y.id_store
WHERE store.id = 1

Или вот такой:

SELECT * FROM `store` 
INNER JOIN `slider` ON store.id = slider.id_store
INNER JOIN `products` ON store.id = products.id_store 
INNER JOIN `product_image` ON store.id = product_image.id_store 
WHERE store.id = 1
```

То вывод результата дублируется. Вот как тут
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но если в запросе использую один JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM `store` 
INNER JOIN `slider` ON store.id = slider.id_store WHERE store.id = 1
```

То всё работает отлично.
Как это исправить?
Буду очень благодарен за ответ)

Comment: Выберите конкретные поля `SELECT store.id as store_id, slider.id as slider_id...`.

Comment: Вообще записи не дублированные а разные. Скажем поле ID берется из нескольких таблиц и на выходе получаются разные кортежи.

Попробуйте явно прописать поля, которые вам нужны.

Comment: Может я что-то понял не так, но я сделал вот так:
SELECT * FROM `store`
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, id_store, slider FROM `slider` GROUP BY id) AS x ON store.id = x.id_store
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, id_store, product_name, rating FROM `products` GROUP BY id) AS y ON store.id = y.id_store
WHERE store.id = 1
Но проблема всё равно не решилась(

Comment: @Aswer3570, вы намеренно из разных таблиц берете поле `id`? Вам уже ответили что они не дублируются, это поля разных таблиц.

`SELECT s.id as store_id FROM store AS s
INNER JOIN slider ON s.id = slider.id_store...`

Comment: @becouse По идее мне нужны все поля. Но как они могут быть разными, если данные дублируются?

Comment: Вам нужны поля ID Из всех таблиц? Тогда нет никакого противоречия. Набор данных разный. Сравните строки в выдаче и увидите, что они разные,
Если вам нужно группировать по каким-то полям, то используйте агрегатные функции.

Comment: Кажется я понял в чем проблема @Aswer3570 рассматривает совпадения по столбцам, а MySQL по сторокам.

Comment: @becouse Мне нужны не id, а нужно связать, между собой, 4 таблицы. Я хочу получить данные из БД, меняя id.
По этому делаю такой запрос:
`SELECT * FROM `store` 
INNER JOIN `slider` ON store.id = slider.id_store
INNER JOIN `products` ON store.id = products.id_store 
INNER JOIN `product_image` ON store.id = product_image.id_store 
WHERE store.id = 1`
Но он дублирует результаты.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, что вы понимаете под дублированием?

Comment: @becouse Ожидалось получить 2 записи, но получаю 4. 2 из которых повторяют предыдущие 2 записи. На скриншоте я показал как это выглядит в БД.

Comment: @Answer3570, ваши данные уникальны, посмотрите на комбинации столбцов id. Вы что то напутали с индексами или с ключами, перепроверьте.